# i want to refresh my page 5 times on one click

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

How can i refresh my page 5 times on just one click here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
<body>
   <button type="button" onClick="Refresh()">Close</button>

 <script>

function Refresh() {

for (var i=0; var i<5; var i++) {
    window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you hope to achieve by reloading the page five times sequentially?

Comment: You could use the localstorage to store a variable and decrement it, or a query string. At page load check the value of the variable to decide to reload or not... I'm wondering what's the aim of such a thing....

Comment: @Quentin Maybe he wants to show investors a 500% uptick in page impressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add query string parameter `refreshesLeft` and on button click redirect to `mypage?refreshesLeft=5`. Add onLoad handler to check if you have query string parameter set, and if yes, decrement it and redirect.

```
<button type="button" onClick="Refresh()">Close</button>

<script>

function Refresh(refreshesLeft) {
  refreshesLeft = refreshesLeft || 5;
  window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href + '?refreshesLeft='+refreshesLeft;
}

function onLoad() {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1)); 
  let rl = params.get("refreshesLeft")
  if (rl) Refresh( (rl | 0 ) -1)
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad)

</script>
```

Comment: Nice answer for an odd question.

Comment: @Waxi thank pal, He might have legacy system that doing something on page load and there is real reason to do this kind of things.